# Solving $(5-2\sqrt6)^{x/2}+ (5+2\sqrt6)^{x/2} = 10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I know the answer is $2$. I guessed it. But how do you do it mathematically?
$$(5-2\sqrt6)^{x/2}+ (5+2\sqrt6)^{x/2} = 10$$

Comment: Since $5-2\sqrt{6} = (5+2\sqrt{6})^{-1}$, your equation is equivalent to finding a root for a quadratic polynomial in $u = (5+2\sqrt{6})^{x/2}$.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that thanks a lot. Y don't u post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(5+2\sqrt{6})^{x/2}=t$ then $\frac{1}{t}=(5-2\sqrt{6})^{x/2}$.
Tthe equation becomes

$$t+\frac{1}{t}=10$$

$$t^2-10t+1=0$$

solve for  $t$ and put  $ t = (5+2\sqrt{6})^{x/2}$.

You will get 2 values of $x$ for each  $t$.

Comment: Just one value of $x$ for each $t$, surely?

Comment: i didn't solve it plz edit if you feel something is wrong